# Databinding IsHighlighted for ComboBoxItems in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

I want to get the ComboBoxItem.IsHighlighted property into my ViewModel. I figured I could set the item container style and do a trigger based on that property but then I got stuck.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StartChapters}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStartChapter}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter ??? />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

All the examples I could find were setting some other UI property and not giving data back to the datacontext.

Anyone know how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a perfect world, we could just bind the `IsHighlighted` property on the `ComboBoxItem` to a property in our ViewModel and set the `Mode` to `OneWayToSource`:

```
<ComboBoxItem IsHighlighted="{Binding MyViewModelBoolProperty}" />
```

However, WPF does **not** allow any bindings to be set on read only dependency properties, even if the mode is `OneWayToSource` (which states our intent to never update the dependency property, only its specified source). There is a connect issue open for this:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540833/onewaytosource-binding-from-a-readonly-dependency-property

In the connect issue, there is a proposed workaround which may work for you. The approach taken is to create a `MultiBinding` to `Tag`, with one of the bindings being to your read-only property, and the other binding being to your ViewModel. A converter is then provided which sets your ViewModel property:

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <l:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Content Placeholder One" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Content Placeholder Two" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Content Placeholder Three" />
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Tag">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsHighlighted" />
                                <Binding />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
```

and the converter:

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values != null && values[0] is bool && values[1] is MyViewModel)
            {
                ((MyViewModel)values[1]).MyBoolProperty = (bool)values[0];
                return (bool)values[0];
            }

            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
```

Not the nicest solution since it involves `Tag` and obfuscates our real intent, but it is effective. Hope this helps!